# Mongos is failing to start and throwing errors, pinging failed for distributed lock pinger. MongoDB 3.4.3 issue

Tags: mongodb

I am facing problem in connecting to a config server replica set and Mongos is throwing lots of errors.
Mongodb version used is 3.4.3 and I have faced the same problem on Amazon Linux and Ubuntu 14.04.
The issue happens even with a standalone MongoDB config server.

Errors are:

```
2017-04-17T01:00:19.368+0530 W SHARDING [replSetDistLockPinger] pinging failed for distributed lock pinger :: caused by :: WriteConcernFailed: waiting for replication timed out. Error details: { wtimeout: true }

WriteConcernFailed: waiting for replication timed out. Error details: { wtimeout: true }
2017-04-17T00:53:48.230+0530 I NETWORK  [mongosMain] Marking host 127.0.0.1:27021 as failed :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 45 -- target:127.0.0.1:27021 db:config expDate:2017-04-17T00:53:48.229+0530 cmd:{ find: "version", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 0|0, t: -1 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
2017-04-17T00:53:48.230+0530 I SHARDING [mongosMain] Operation timed out  :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 45 -- target:127.0.0.1:27021 db:config expDate:2017-04-17T00:53:48.229+0530 cmd:{ find: "version", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 0|0, t: -1 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
2017-04-17T00:53:48.230+0530 W SHARDING [mongosMain] Error initializing sharding state, sleeping for 2 seconds and trying again :: caused by :: ExceededTimeLimit: Error loading clusterID :: caused by :: Operation timed out, request was RemoteCommand 45 -- target:127.0.0.1:27021 db:config expDate:2017-04-17T00:53:48.229+0530 cmd:{ find: "version", readConcern: { level: "majority", afterOpTime: { ts: Timestamp 0|0, t: -1 } }, maxTimeMS: 30000 }
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Below are details of the configurations I am using:

```
rsconfig:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rsconfig",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:52.382Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "term" : NumberLong(1),
    "syncingTo" : "127.0.0.1:27022",
    "configsvr" : true,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        },
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1492370750, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(1)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1492369489, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
        }
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "127.0.0.1:27020",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 1599,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1492370750, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:50Z"),
            "syncingTo" : "127.0.0.1:27022",
            "configVersion" : 1,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "127.0.0.1:27021",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 2,
            "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
            "uptime" : 1260,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1492370750, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1492369489, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:50Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:04:49Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:51.325Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:51.333Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "syncingTo" : "127.0.0.1:27022",
            "configVersion" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "127.0.0.1:27022",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 1260,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1492370750, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "optimeDurable" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1492369489, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(-1)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:50Z"),
            "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:04:49Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:51.325Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:25:50.792Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1492369500, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2017-04-16T19:05:00Z"),
            "configVersion" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Below is the config for one of the config servers.
    # mongod.conf

```
# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: mongodb1
  journal:
    enabled: false
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: mongod1.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27020
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
  replSetName: rsconfig
sharding:
  clusterRole: configsvr

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, the problem was with the configuration. There were some writes with write concern "majority" on the config servers. And I, to "optimize", disabled journal on the config servers.